# Ajax value remain same after reload page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am using 2 drop down lists. One list comes from Ajax code. My question is this, how do I keep the ensure the value remains in the second drop down while the form is reloaded. I am using trigger change event for value of model drop down.
My code is below

---i

- Trigger Change Jquery i used from stack overflow.
  --i have one more table name model the value of vehicle comes from make table.

--

```
<?php
 include "conn.php";
 $exe=$con->query("select * from make");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax</title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#make').trigger("change");
       //console.log(make);
       function getModel()
        {
                var mid= document.getElementById("make").value;
                //console.log(mid);
                $.ajax({
                          type:"POST",
                          url :"model.php",
                          data:"makeid="+mid,
                          success:function(ans)
                          {
                              document.getElementById("model").innerHTML=ans;


                           }
                      });
            }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Make</td>
            <td>
                <select name="make" id="make" onchange="return getModel()">
                    <?php
                    while ($row=$exe->fetch_object())
                     {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row->make_id?>">
                        <?php if(isset($_POST['make']) && $_POST['make']==$row->make_id) echo "selected";?>                          
                        <?php echo $row->make_name?></option>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Model</td>
            <td><select name="model" id="model">
                <option value="">.....</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: might be a caching issues, have you tried clearing browser cache on reload ?

Comment: i tried but not working .i am asking while reloading of page first diallog box value remian same i m using this code for first

Comment: <?php if(isset($_POST['make']) && $_POST['make']==$row->make_id) echo "selected";?>

Answer (score 1):

This code will store your dropdown value to the storage

```
let dropdownModel= document.getElementById("model").value
localStorage.setItem("myValue", dropdownModel);
```

This code will load your stored value from your dropdown and put it back to it

```
document.getElementById("model").value = localStorage.getItem("myValue");
```

Comment: dropdown list value comes through ajax which is save in other file .and i wrote change event in first dropdown .

Comment: So you need an event that is triggered when you select the value from the dropdown, and will use my first 2 lines of code, and when you refresh the page you load my third line of code to prefill the dropdown. You can also put it in your `success` ajax call if you need to but that's up to you.

Comment: Thank u for help ,,but stil its not working ..value of model drop down not keep remain ..

Comment: Help me to set dropdwon list value accrding to first box ..this code is not working .by trigger i got id of first dropdown ..but at the time of reload but not in the box..

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to call on change,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#make").on('change', function(){
     var make_id= $("#make option:selected").val();


                $('#model').empty();

                    $.ajax({
                            url: 'model.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: "text",
                            data: {
                                make_id: make_id,


                            }
                        }).done(function(data){
                          $('#model').html(data);


          });//ajax success function
}).change();




});
```

in model.php make a drop down like this

```
<option>A</option>
<option selected >B</option>
```

Comment: did you checked in debug, there might be some syntax error

Comment: Help me to set dropdwon list value accrding to first box ..this code is not working .by trigger i got id of first dropdown ..but at the time of reload but not in the box..

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can get the second drop down names model value. Then you can select it when the form has loaded.

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#make").trigger('change');
    $("#model").selectedIndex = <?php echo $_POST['model']?>;
  });
</script>
```